# Two Step Verification. 4 digits vs 6 digits

Tags: security, authentication

From a security level standpoint (such as Server, DataBase, Token Code, Authorization, Authentication, etc.) in regarding the Two Step Verification, usually Apple send a total of **4** digits security code vs Google send a total of **6** digits security code. What are the main differences?

Answer (score 2):

The number of digits in such a [one-time password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) is determined by the acceptable risk that an attacker who doesn't receive the verification code will be able to guess it (lucky guess). This risk takes into account several factors:

- the probability that an attacker will be able to guess;
- the negative consequences of an correct guess by an attacker;
- the probability and the negative consequences if the code is too long and this discourages the user to use the service.

For an $n$-digit code, if there is a single valid code and the code is generated at random, then the probability of a lucky guess is $10^{-n}$. That's 1/10,000 for a 4-digit code, 1/1,000,000 for a 6-digit code. These are usually acceptable figures when the one-time code is a [second factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) (usually complemented by knowing a static password or possessing a physical device); they would be grossly insufficient if the code alone was enough to access a service.

When the code is sent from a remote server to the user's device, there is generally a single valid code which is randomly generated. Some one-time password schemes don't require communication between the server and the user's device, but instead have both sides generate a [pseudo-random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) code in the same way using a shared secret key and a counter. In this case, there are usually several valid codes, to allow for desynchronization between the client and the server; this requires a slightly longer code to compensate for the increased number of possible lucky guesses.